# share content in whatsapp jquery break line

Tags: javascript, jquery, whatsapp

This is my code to share the content of a web page on WhatsApp with jquery. but inside divblock3 there is text with line breaks `<br />`

```
<div class='divblock3'><p><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy .<br /> <br /> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy textntly.<br /> <br /> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy textntly.
```

whatsapp does not interpret as a line break...

any idea how to replace the `<br />` with a `"%0a"`, so that whatsapp interprets them as line breaks

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

(function clickMe() {
  const button = document.getElementById("button");
  var divblock1 = $('.divblock1').text();
  var divblock2 = $('.divblock2').text();
 var divblock3 = $('.divblock3').text();
var message = encodeURIComponent(divblock1)+" %0a "+encodeURIComponent(divblock2)+" %0a "+encodeURIComponent(divblock3);
  button.addEventListener("click", event => {
    // Whatsapp Message on Button Click
    window.open("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text="+message)
  });
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried styling your elements as block level elements using CSS?

Comment: You have invalid html structure, you can't nest p tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery's `replace` function can search for all instances of `<br>` and replaces it with the value you specify. Also Jquery's `.text()` function removes all HTMLtags, but you want to keep those because you want to replace `<br>` with `%0a`. So lets use the function `.html()` instead.

And I would recommand that you remove the `/` in `<br />` it isn't necessary and will cause problems otherwise with the new code.

Small HTML edit like

```
<div class='divblock3'>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy .<br> <br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy textntly.<br> <br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy textntly.
</div>
```

New lines in JS

```
var divblock3 = $('.divblock3').html();
divblock3 = divblock3.replace(/<br>/g, '\n');
divblock3 = $('<div></div>').html(divblock3);
divblock3 = divblock3.text();
```

Updated example script
(At first I didn't account for the encodeURIComponent later on, it's fixed in this update by using `\n` instead of `%0A`)

```js
function clickMe() {
  const button = document.getElementById("button");
  var divblock1 = $('.divblock1').text();
  var divblock2 = $('.divblock2').text();

  // the new lines
  var divblock3 = $('.divblock3').html();
  divblock3 = divblock3.replace(/<br>/g, '\n');
  divblock3 = $('<div></div>').html(divblock3);
  divblock3 = divblock3.text();
  
  var message = encodeURIComponent(divblock1) + "%0A" + encodeURIComponent(divblock2) + "%0A" +  encodeURIComponent(divblock3);
  
  window.open("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text="+message, '_blank');
  // and for debugging purposes you can copy this:
  console.log("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text="+message);


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='divblock1'>
 Subject: Strange text editor
</div>

<div class='divblock2'>
 Department: IT
</div>

<div class='divblock3'>
Message: Every time I type somehting it turns to:<br><br>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy .<br> <br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy textntly.<br> <br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy textntly
</div>

<button onclick="clickMe()">
Send message
</button>
```

Comment: It works but I think that after replacing <br>.. them it is to show again as text...

Comment: I've update the answer. I didn't account for the encodeURIComponent. I have now, instead of replace `<br>` with `%0A` we're gonne replace it with '\n' what is a UNIX command for a new line.

Comment: this work perfect, but there is another problem if there is another string in the code for example: <p></p> ... this appears in the message

Comment: Okay, in that case. We first take the content out of the div. Then replace the `<br>` (we already did this) and now will put the replaced text back in a div we create with jQuery. Then from this new div we use the function .text() and it works just lik divblock1 and divblock2